# Why test case is stopped even if FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE is used

Tags: selenium, error-handling, katalon-studio

I don’t understand why test case is stopped whereas I use `FailureHandling_CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE` into caller.

**Code into caller:**

```
...
switch (testCaseName) {
    case testCaseName:
        WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase(testCaseName), param, FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE)
        break
}
...
```

**Error into callee:**

This error occured into test case called with `WebUI.callTestCase(...)`

> Caused by: com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException: Web element with id: ‘XXX’ located by ‘By.xpath: XXX’]’ not found

But, if I use `FailureHandling_CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE` callee must be stopped, but not caller right?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to partially reproduce the issue. I wrote the following two test cases:

TC1: **Caller**

```
println ">>>> start caller"
if(!WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase("Callee"), null, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)){
    println ">>>> success!"
}
println ">>>> end caller"
```

TC2: **Callee**

```
println ">>>> start callee"
assert 0
```

This is my console output with `FailureHandling.OPTIONAL`:

```
2019-07-03 12:43:41.851 DEBUG testcase.Caller                          - 1: println(">>>> start caller")
>>>> start caller
2019-07-03 12:43:41.855 DEBUG testcase.Caller                          - 2: if (!(callTestCase(findTestCase("Callee"), null, OPTIONAL)))
2019-07-03 12:43:41.934 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - --------------------
2019-07-03 12:43:41.934 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - CALL Test Cases/Callee
2019-07-03 12:43:42.086 DEBUG testcase.Callee                          - 1: println(">>>> start callee")
>>>> start callee
2019-07-03 12:43:42.087 DEBUG testcase.Callee                          - 2: assert 0
2019-07-03 12:43:42.095 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ Test Cases/Callee FAILED.
Reason:
Assertion failed: 

assert 0

    at Callee.run(Callee:18)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    ....

2019-07-03 12:43:42.104 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - END CALL Test Cases/Callee
2019-07-03 12:43:42.104 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - --------------------
2019-07-03 12:43:42.109 WARN  c.k.k.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain  - Unable to call Test Case 'Test Cases/Callee' (Root cause: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Call Test Case 'Test Cases/Callee' failed
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.builtin.CallTestCaseKeyword$_callTestCase_closure1.doCall(CallTestCaseKeyword.groovy:63)
    ....
Caused by: Assertion failed: 

assert 0

    at Callee.run(Callee:18)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    ...
)
2019-07-03 12:43:42.110 DEBUG testcase.Caller                          - 1: println(">>>> success!")
>>>> success!
2019-07-03 12:43:42.111 DEBUG testcase.Caller                          - 3: println(">>>> end caller")
>>>> end caller
2019-07-03 12:43:43.067 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - END Test Cases/Caller
```

So, **TC2** is failed, but `WebUI.callTestCase()` throws an exception that is interpreted as WARN in the logs, so **TC1** is passed.

When I switch to `FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE`, that is interpreted as ERROR in the logs and both **TC1** and **TC2** are failed. More on failure handling [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/failure-handling.html).

I believe this is a bug in Katalon Studio. But, I think you can use `FailureHandling.OPTIONAL` as a workaround to get the desired result.

Comment: I will try with `OPTIONAL` and will come back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I added a link to failure handling in Katalon Studio. Basically, CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE is used when you wish to continue the test execution after a failure if you, for example, wish to find other defects after the point of failure. But the whole test will still be marked as failed.

Comment: My goal is to execute a list a test cases sequentially. If a test case failed, it is stopped and the next one start, etc... until the last one.

Comment: You can do that using test suites, you know? Anyway, this approach is valid, too. Did you try with optional failure handling?

Comment: Yep we were using test suites before. However we are now using a new approach and `callTestCase()` is a better way than test suites. About optional failure handling it seems to be good. I will confirm you that tomorrow when all test cases will have been executed.

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed. Thanks.